# How to limit the camera rotation on the oculus?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, limit, unityscript, oculus

I want to know if it is possible to limit the rotation of the oculus camera, so that the camera stops moving when the limit point is reached. I looked in several blogs for the answer, but most say don't do it or why do you need it.

I have a scene with a bird eye view of a gameworld (in which you can select the levels). But it only covers a certain part of the whole 360 view and if a user accidently turns the oculus. He/she will look at only the sky, and they don't know that they have to turn 180 degrees. So i want to limit the camera movement in order for the "world" to always be (partly) in the view

I know that it is not great for the user if you limit the camera movement of the oculus, but i only need it for one short scene.

Thanks for the help xd

Comment: If this were in the gamedev stack exchange I'd suggest that you change or add to the sky background to make it obvious that the user needs to turn around or reset orientation (maybe even just some text saying so). You could also have multiple instances of the menu, or it could rotate. But on SO I think an answer to the direct question makes sense. I'll try this out with my rift when I get a chance: I'm not sure how the transforms are set up in Unity.

Comment: You absolutely do not want to block the camera rotation. This will cause the view to be headlocked which is a direct pathway to vomitland. This is VR, if the user doesn't see anything interesting his first reflex will be to look around. (So I guess what I'm saying is, "don't do it, you don't need it").

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, i was a bit busy with work. First of thanks for the responses. Joan, I also figured you'll get a vomit effect by blocking the view, but i just want to experience it for myself first in order to judge the seriousness of it. I already made version in of the game without the limit and tested it on a few people, but their reflex was "i don't see anything, maybe it's still loading or fading in in a few seconds". Personally I don't like to add additional stuff to the sky background like text/images. But im eager to hear/see @31eee384 idea on directing the user.

Comment: And I'm sorry for not getting to this. :P To direct the user I can think of a few non-text ways: 1. Make the background visually interesting, with an obvious light source coming from the menu. ("Where's the light coming from?") 2. A sound effect coming from the direction of the menu. (Of course that only works on people who have healthy hearing.) Just having multiple instances/mirrors of the menu isn't "direction," but would work to simply always have a menu in the field of view. I agree with Joan though: especially when VR becomes mainstream people will be used to looking around.

Comment: Alright, I figured as such! but thank you guys for your time though!